# Removing escape characters from a string received from Android socket in Python

Tags: android, python, sockets

```
import sqlite3
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from socket import *
import sys
import socket

HOST = "192.168.43.123" #local host  IT SHOWS AN ERROR WHEN I USE MY PC's IP ADDRESS  47.11.229.90 127.0.0.1 192.168.43.123
PORT = 9999 #open port 18000 for connection
s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print("Bind error, Error code: ",e.strerror,"Message: ",e.strerror)
    sys.exit(1)
print("Bind successful")
s.listen(10) #how many connections can it receive at one time
print("In the loop")
while True:
    connect_device, addr = s.accept()  # accept the connection
    print("Connected by: ", addr)
    #msg1 = 'Thank you for connecting' + "\r\n"
    #connect_device.send(msg1.encode('ascii'))
    data = connect_device.recv(4096)  # how many bytes of data will the server receive
    data = data.decode('ascii','ignore')
    print("Received: ", repr(data))

    conn = sqlite3.connect("ciao.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    #string = "Hey tell me something about dengue"
    #string2 = string.lower()
    string = repr(data)
    string2 = string.lower()
    list_items = word_tokenize(string2)
    list_items2 = []
    escape_chars = ['\x00\x00','\x00\x01','\x00\x02','\x00\x03','\x00\x04','\x00\x05','\x00\x06','\x00\x07','\x00\x08','\x00\x09']
    for st in list_items:
        for j in escape_chars:
            if j in st:
                print(j,"List item is ",st)
                list_items2.append(st.strip(j))
    print("List items = ",list_items2)
    Greetings = ['hi', "hey"]
    c.execute("SELECT Disease_Name FROM ciao")
    data = c.fetchall()
    data2 = []
    for i in data:
        for j in i:
            if j is not None:
                data2.append(j)

    print("data2 = ",data2)
    msg = ""
    print("loop starts")
    for i in list_items2:
        print(i)
        print("Data = ",data2)

        if i in data2:
            if 'symptoms' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Symptoms from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,))
                sym = c.fetchall()
                for j in sym:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'remedial' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Remedial_Measures from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'medicines' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Medicines from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'diagnostic' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Diagnostic_tests from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'hospitals' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Related_Hospitals from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if not('symptoms' in list_items2) and not('remedial' in list_items2) and not('medicines' in list_items2) and not('diagnostic' in list_items2) and not('hospitals' in list_items2):
                c.execute("SELECT * from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,) )
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "

        else:
            if i in Greetings:
                if len(list_items) == 1 or len(list_items) == 0:
                    msg = "Hello I am Pi"
    if msg == "":
        msg = "Sorry"
    print(msg)
    connect_device.sendall(msg.encode('ascii'))
    #connect_device.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    conn.close()
    connect_device.close()

s.close()
```

I have connected Android client to python server using sockets, whenever I send a message from android to python server some escape characters are added.
For example:
if I send 'hello how are you?'
my python receives '\x00\x05hello how are you?'

In this, the first seven characters are common everytime i.e. '\x00\x0' and the last character is generated randomly from 0 to 9 each time. 
I tried using a loop to strip those characters but it doesn't work. 
Please check my code and suggest any changes. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? what do you get and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Did you try using a Regex? That would be much more efficient.